# Catch .find errors in Excel when 'What' is not found

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a Excel VBA function that's been working for quite some time. However I found that when `i` doesn't exist in this code:

```
Dim rowNum as Integer
for i = 1 to 20
    rowNum = Columns(SiteNumCol).Find(What:=i, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).row
    <other stuff>
Next i
```

An error is returned. I tried refactoring the code to include a check:

```
    rowNum = Columns(SiteNumCol).Find(What:=i, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).row
    If Not rowNum = 0 Then
        <other stuff>
    End If
Next i
```

However it still errored out at the `rownum =` line. I thought it might be as I'm calling the row number of nothing, so tried this test:

```
test = Columns(NumCol).Find(What:=i, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not test Is Nothing Then
    rowNum = Columns(NumCol).Find(What:=i, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).row
```

It now errors out at the If statement with a 424 "Object required" error; I think this is because 'test' is currently a double as it errors out on the first iteration. If I change the test to `= "0"` it goes through iterations until the one that isn't found and then it fails because at `test =` because of good ol' 91 "Object Variable not set"

How can I successfully catch .find errors when the What is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so. You were pretty close, just missing the Set I think.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim rowNum As Long
For i = 1 To 20
    Set r = Columns(SiteNumCol).Find(What:=i, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then rowNum = r.Row
    <other stuff>
Next i
```

Comment: Awesome! What threw me was reusing the same code with the missing `.row`, hence making it a range object. As soon as I saw your answer the penny dropped!