# .ThisCell does not work properly when opening new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a follow-up question on my previous one which can be found here: [user-defined formula shows error when opening new workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982773/user-defined-formula-shows-error-when-opening-new-workbook)

I adjusted my code as shown below. However, each time I am opening another workbook (with macros), the formula shows an error. What am I missing? I added `Set WB = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Parent`, but the error still appears.

I tried to implement a `Do Until` error dissipates loop, but this is way too complicated for my machine.

```
Function cons_market_values() As Double
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Parent
    Dim total_market As Double: total_market = 0#
    Dim ws As Worksheet: For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(ws.Cells.Find("Kurswert in Fondswährung", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value) Then GoTo NextIteration
        If ws.Cells.Find("Kurswert in Fondswährung", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value = "N/A" Then GoTo NextIteration
        Dim foundCell As Range: Set foundCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Kurswert in Fondswährung", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Debug.Print foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            total_market = total_market + foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
NextIteration:
    Next ws
    cons_market_values = total_market
End Function
```

Here the code that is used once the new workbook opens. It seems this is causing the error, i.e., that the UDF do not work anymore.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'------------------------------------------------
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").ListObjects("tbl_log_historic").HeaderRowRange.Offset(-1, 0)) <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Immobilien weekly").Range("rng_week_one").value - 7 Then
        MsgBox "XXX", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Hinweis"
        Call eRoll.rolling_open
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dashboard").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dashboard").Range("D7").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dashboard").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
''------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

The code called `eRoll.rolling_open` looks as follows:

```
Sub rolling()
'-------------------------------------
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Immobilien weekly")
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = WS.ListObjects("tbl_fonds_weekly")
Dim tbl_log_historic As ListObject: Set tbl_log_historic = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").ListObjects("tbl_log_historic")
Dim tbl_log_entries As ListObject: Set tbl_log_entries = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").ListObjects("tbl_log")
Dim rng_date As Range: Set rng_date = WS.Range("rng_week_one")
Dim j As Integer, rng_found As Range, rng_date_found As Range
'-------------------------------------
tbl_log_historic.ListColumns.Add
tbl_log_historic.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, tbl_log_historic.Range.Columns.Count).value = rng_date.value - 7
tbl_log_historic.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, tbl_log_historic.Range.Columns.Count).Offset(-1, 0).value = rng_date.value - 7
Dim n As Integer: For n = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

TryAgain:
On Error Resume Next
    Set rng_found = tbl_log_historic.ListColumns("ISIN").DataBodyRange.Find(tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(n, tbl.ListColumns("ISIN").Index), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    j = tbl_log_historic.ListColumns(CStr(rng_date.value - 7)).Range.Column

If (Not rng_found Is Nothing) Then
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(n, tbl.ListColumns("1").Index).Copy: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").Cells(rng_found.Row, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else:
        tbl_log_historic.ListRows.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").Cells(tbl_log_historic.Range.Rows(tbl_log_historic.Range.Rows.Count).Row, tbl_log_historic.ListColumns("ISIN").Range.Column).value = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(n, tbl.ListColumns("ISIN").Index).value
        GoTo TryAgain
End If
Next n
'-------------------------------------
For n = tbl.ListColumns("2").Index To tbl.Range.Columns.Count
    tbl.ListColumns(n).DataBodyRange.Copy: tbl.ListColumns(n - 1).DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    tbl.ListColumns(n).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
Next n
'-------------------------------------
Dim target_row As Integer: target_row = tbl_log_entries.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + tbl_log_entries.HeaderRowRange.Row + 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").Cells(target_row, tbl_log_entries.ListColumns("Nutzer").Range.Column).value = Environ("Username")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").Cells(target_row, tbl_log_entries.ListColumns("Datum Eintrag").Range.Column).value = Date
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").Cells(target_row, tbl_log_entries.ListColumns("Fonds").Range.Column).value = "Weekly Roll"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("log").Cells(target_row, tbl_log_entries.ListColumns("Datum").Range.Column).value = rng_date.value
'-------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that is what is failing and not the `.find` method?

Comment: Interesting view.... What's wrong with ```.find``` method?

Comment: If `find` fails to find something it returns an empty object, empty objects have no `.offset` property. Since you are looping through the worksheets and adding the `.find` return directly to the arraylist I find it hard to believe this would ever run without throwing that error. You need to break that into multiple lines and test the return of `.find`

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565381/catch-find-errors-in-excel-when-what-is-not-found

Comment: Thanks for explaining that further. Actually, I deleted those checks in my code above to reduce the noise for the forum. My checks come first in the ```For Each``` loop before adding something to the array. So, this should actually not be the reason why the code crashes when I am opening a new workbook even though my code above indeed would.

Comment: Is this in an add-in?  If the formula code is in the same workbook as the formula cell then why not use `ThisWorkbook` in place of `Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Parent` ?

Comment: Tried this as well. Not working either.

Comment: I added ```Application.Volatile True``` at the top of my function, but it's not the solution to my problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Running your code as-is, I do get an error `#VALUE!` in the cell on the worksheet. This is because your `Find` statement is not finding the value. You mention that there is error-checking code in the "full" version of your function, but we can't see that in your post.

My testing shows that simply separating the `Find` statement into multiple lines (which does NOT slow the function down at all!) and checking for the value seems to fix the error, at least in my test workbooks.

```
Option Explicit

Function show_market_values() As Double
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Parent
    
    Dim arValues As Collection
    Set arValues = New Collection
    
    Dim total_market As Double
    total_market = 0#
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Dim foundCell As Range
        Set foundCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="", _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            total_market = total_market + foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next ws
    show_market_values = total_market
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your code, but it didn't work. I adjusted my initial question above combining your code with my checks which still were necessary. The problem remains, however, when I open a new workbook that contains macros itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: I figured out that the error only appears if the new workbook contains a code that is initiated at the workbook open. Otherwise my UDF does not give an error. At the workbook open of the new workbook I am using ```ThisWorkbook```.

Comment: Running code in another workbook, using `ThisWorkbook`, will not "reset" which workbook any of your code is referencing. But it is highly suspicious that some code running on open would affect this code as well -- to provide any more detailed analysis here, we'll have to see that code also.

Comment: Another comment on your updated code though, my personal habit is to write statements once. In your case, the `Find` statement is forced to run twice (if it does find the target value). That's why my short code example creates an intermediate variable `foundCell` and uses that as the test.

Comment: I added the additional code in my initial question above. Now, it gets quite complex...